# Color misaligned in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

In my understanding, if an image and imageView size is not the same, it will be marked as magenta. In my app, I have a image called myImage with myImage.imageView = {50,50}, myImage.image= {63,63} with scale=2, however, it is marked in yellow, not magenta. My questions are:

1. Since its image and imageView are not the same size, why it is not in magenta?
2. Why it is in yellow? I loaded the image by using

`[UIImage imageNamed:@"Rainbow_Circle.png"]`.

`myImage.frame = {0,0,50, 50},`

why there is a stretch happened? How could I check stretch?

3. Does the scale matter? After I loaded it from .png, the scale is 2, not 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally we set the frame for the imageView. If the image's size is not compatible wih the size of the imageView, it'll be displayed based on the Content mode you set for the imageView.

For example 
**UIViewContentModeScaleToFill**  scales the content to fit the size of itself by changing the aspect ratio of the content if necessary.

**UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit** scales the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.

In your case since the image size is smaller than the imageView and if you would have used say **UIViewContentModeScaleToFill**, then the image could appear stretched.

In your case you should have given a background colour as magenta for the imageView. The logic for magenta and yellow is not clear.

Also make sure that you use layoutIfNeeded method if you are trying to set the frame before the image is drawn, ie, if used in **viewDidLoad**.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! It is in magenta because the cell's frame of the image is not integral. Once it get fix, all the subviews of it works well.